# return format inconsistencies using download.file() vs xml2::read_html()

Tags: r, curl, xml2

I am trying to parse the index page of an FTP site in order to get a list of files based on the contents of `<a href = "">` tags. I'm struggling to understand why I am getting different formats in the result when trying to download the index of an ftp folder in different ways (the results have different DOCTYPE specifications). Consider the following:

```r
  tf = tempfile()
  download.file("ftp://ftp.dfg.ca.gov/IEP_Zooplankton/", tf)
  file.show(tf)
```

Result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>FTP directory /IEP_Zooplankton/ at ftp.dfg.ca.gov</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H2 ID="WinINetFtpDirectory">FTP directory /IEP_Zooplankton/ at ftp.dfg.ca.gov</H2>
<HR>
<A HREF="..">Up to higher level directory</A><BR><PRE>
09/06/2019 01:26PM      Directory <A HREF="/IEP_Zooplankton/./"><B>.</B></A>
09/06/2019 01:26PM      Directory <A HREF="/IEP_Zooplankton/../"><B>..</B></A>
07/09/2019 12:00AM     11,393,654 <A HREF="/IEP_Zooplankton/1972-2018CBMatrix.xlsx">1972-2018CBMatrix.xlsx</A>
05/09/2019 12:00AM      3,174,362 <A HREF="/IEP_Zooplankton/1972-2018MysidMatrix.xlsx">1972-2018MysidMatrix.xlsx</A>
05/09/2019 12:00AM      6,058,037 <A HREF="/IEP_Zooplankton/1972-2018Pump%20Matrix.xlsx">1972-2018Pump Matrix.xlsx</A>
05/09/2019 12:00AM         16,238 <A HREF="/IEP_Zooplankton/ReadMeZooplanktonStudyMatricesMay2019.docx">ReadMeZooplanktonStudyMatricesMay2019.docx</A>
09/06/2019 01:26PM      1,737,932 <A HREF="/IEP_Zooplankton/ZooplanktonMetadataSept2019.pdf">ZooplanktonMetadataSept2019.pdf</A>
05/01/2008 12:00AM        202,752 <A HREF="/IEP_Zooplankton/ZP%20Monitoring%20Station%20Map%20Historic.ppt">ZP Monitoring Station Map Historic.ppt</A>
10/31/2017 12:00AM        199,023 <A HREF="/IEP_Zooplankton/ZPCoreAndCurrentStationsAug2017.pdf">ZPCoreAndCurrentStationsAug2017.pdf</A>
</PRE>
<HR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

However, if I try to do the equivalent action with `xml2::read_html()` (or `curl::curl_fetch_memory()`) I get a completely different format:

```
xml = xml2::read_html("ftp://ftp.dfg.ca.gov/IEP_Zooplankton/")
```

Result (you can print the full page contents to the console by doing `as.character(xml)`):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Sep  6 13:26 .
drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Sep  6 13:26 ..
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group    11393654 Jul  9  2019 1972-2018CBMatrix.xlsx
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group     3174362 May  9  2019 1972-2018MysidMatrix.xlsx
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group     6058037 May  9  2019 1972-2018Pump Matrix.xlsx
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group       16238 May  9  2019 ReadMeZooplanktonStudyMatricesMay2019.docx
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group     1737932 Sep  6 13:26 ZooplanktonMetadataSept2019.pdf
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group      202752 May  1  2008 ZP Monitoring Station Map Historic.ppt
-rw-rw-rw-   1 user     group      199023 Oct 31  2017 ZPCoreAndCurrentStationsAug2017.pdf
</p></body></html>
```

The first result (via `download.file()`) is parseable using the `xml2::xml_find_*()` functions, but the latter is not. Why am I getting different formats for the same file? How can I ensure that I get the former format (i.e. the one with the `<a>` tags)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it does not explain *why* the format of an FTP index page downloaded with 
`download.file()` is different from that downloaded using `curl::curl_download()`, 
I did find [this gist](https://gist.github.com/adamhsparks/18f7702906f33dd66788e0078979ff9a) which provides an alternative solution using `curl` to accomplish the original task: get a list of files in the FTP directory.

```r
library(curl)

con = curl(url = url, "r", handle = new_handle(dirlistonly = TRUE))
files = readLines(con)
close(con)
print(files)
```

> [1] "1972-2018CBMatrix.xlsx"
>   [2] "1972-2018MysidMatrix.xlsx"
>   [3] "1972-2018Pump Matrix.xlsx"
>   [4] "ReadMeZooplanktonStudyMatricesMay2019.docx"
>   [5] "ZooplanktonMetadataSept2019.pdf"
>   [6] "ZP Monitoring Station Map Historic.ppt"
>   [7] "ZPCoreAndCurrentStationsAug2017.pdf"

Answer (score 0):

I found that your ftp link timed out so I can't give you a reproducible example, but I think if you do:

```r
xml <- xml2::read_html("ftp://ftp.dfg.ca.gov/IEP_Zooplankton/")
link_nodes <- xml2::xml_find_all(xml, xpath = "//a") 
xml2::xml_attr(link_nodes, "href")
```

You should get a vector of all the links on the page you need.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear: the `as.character()` was just to get the character representation of the contents for printing in the SO post, since the `print` statement for `xml_document` objects does not show the full contents. Your code is exactly what I expected to work, but if you run the code you posted you'll see that `link_nodes` is `{xml_nodeset (0)}`, because there are no `<a>` tags as I described.

Comment: @mikeck I can't get any response from the server at the moment. In the meantime, have you tried the `rvest` library?

Comment: `rvest` is just a wrapper around `xml2` and gives the same result, i.e. the contents of the file in the second form (no `<a>` tags). This is the same format as returned by `curl::curl_download()` or `curl::curl_fetch_memory()`. The only other thing I can think of is that the issue is related to differences in how the user agent or content type is specified in `download.file()` vs `curl`, but I have tried a variety of different settings and always get the same result.

Comment: This is not an encoding issue, the entire contents and arrangement of the files are different. I found a solution that works using `curl`, but it does not explain why different download methods yield different file contents.